# Как сделать ссылку на JSP страницу в меню (Spring MVC + web)

Tags: java, html, веб-программирование, spring, java-ee

Я написал проект где хочу чтобы в меню при нажатии на вкладку "студенты" выпадал список и там в списке при нажатий на "список всех студентов" меня направило сразу же на страницу allStudents.jsp
Я написал но почему пишет что страница не найдена

menutemplate.jsp

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>

<header>
  <a href="" class="logo">Школа Программирования</a>
  <nav>
      <ul class="topmenu">
        <li><a href="">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="submenu-link">Студенты</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="/WEB-INF/views/allStudents.jsp">Список студентов</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Проекты</a></li>
        <li><a href="">О нас</a></li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Здесь раньше на этой странице я нажимал на кнопку "показать всех студентов" и меня сразу же направляло туда, но сейчас я хочу чтобы все работало через меню

index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style><%@include file="/css/style.css"%></style>
        <title>Home Page</title>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="bg">
        <div class ="pokaz">
            <form action="allStudents" method="post">
                 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Показать всех студентов">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

StudentController.java

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.Student;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.service.StudentService;
import java.nio.file.FileSystemException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class StudentController {



    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    // Constructor based Dependency Injection
    private StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hello() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("index");
        return mv;
    }

    // Get All Users
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})

    public ModelAndView displayAllUser() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudents");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayNewUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudent");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addStudent")
    public String saveNewStudent(@RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file)
            throws IOException {

        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
            Student student = new Student();
            student.setSurname(surname);
            student.setName(name);
            student.setAvatar(studentService.saveAvatarImage(file).getName());
            studentService.saveStudent(student);
        }
        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }



    @GetMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/editStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

   @PostMapping(value = "/editStudent")

    public ModelAndView saveEditedUser(@RequestParam("id") Long id,

            @RequestParam("name") String name,

            @RequestParam("surname") String surname,

            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");

       try {

            studentService.updateStudent(name, surname, file, studentService.getStudentById(id));

         }

        catch (FileSystemException ex){

            ex.printStackTrace();

         }

        catch (IOException e) {

             return new ModelAndView("error");

         }

        return mv;
    }

   @GetMapping(value = "/deleteStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
         studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");

        return mv;

    }





 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Сорри, что поспешил с вопросом у меня получилось

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>

<header>
  <a href="" class="logo">Школа Программирования</a>
  <nav>
      <ul class="topmenu">
        <li><a href="">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="submenu-link">Студенты</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="allStudents">Список студентов</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Проекты</a></li>
        <li><a href="">О нас</a></li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```